# heroku running problem

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am learning ruby from this guide http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:deploying, and I am trying to install and make heroku to work. I added heroku to the PATH variable, (I am using ubuntu) bun when i type #command: herokuit returns this:

```
"/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in 'report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>=0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in 'activate'
...
...
..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't installed the Heroku gem;

```
sudo gem install heroku
```

Comment: do you see it listed when you do `gem list`

Comment: soryr, it seems i had to run the command for the thrid time, and now it works! thanks!

Comment: cool...don't forget to mark this as the answer by clicking the tick :)